# Does it exist: Latching Relay with Manual Switch

Tags: switches, relay

I'm looking for a latching relay (so I can control its state remotely) with a manual switch (preferably with a rocker style switch, so I can control its state locally).

Do these exist as I'm struggling to find one?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of just down-voting (for which I see no reason to) it would be more constructive to leave a comment/answer explaining why...

Comment: I don't see a reason for a downvote either, and I agree it would be good to leave a comment.  But, of course *you* wouldn't see a reason for a downvote, so telling us that is no information and will just make it more likely someone else will downvote this too.

Comment: It looks like a shopping question. No design is involved.

Comment: For what it is worth: I recall seeing such a relay once, so they do exist. IMO 'does xxx exist' is a valid type of question, especially when the question does not ask for a source.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen  ... provided that the asker has done extensive preliminary research before posting.  (I don't see anything too wrong with this question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't find one, consider the option of having a local switch. Wire it in like you would the light-switches at the top and bottom of a staircase. Whatever the state of the switch at the bottom of the stairs, the switch at the top can always activate and deactivate the light.

[image]

Now,.... who knows how to convert it to a local with two remotes?

Comment: That's a really good idea. If I cant find anything like I described, I might just do that! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I looked for something like this a while ago. Doing a quick search, look at things like the HFE10-2

also keep in mind that depending on the type of switching you are doing, it doesn't take a lot to create a local trigger that delivers the same switching current to the relay with just a local spst button

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of is the "NVR Switch" built around a relay, commonly used in machine tools. One green button to start it (energise the relay, which then drives the load and holds itself on) and a big red button to stop (breaking the relay coil circuit).

It's normal to take at least the "STOP" switch connections to remote locations, to allow emergency stop switches in obvious places.

It's deliberately NOT a latching relay so that it also switches off when power fails - the last thing you want is for unattended machines to restart when the lights go back on!