# Switch that is physically closed, and electrically opened

Tags: switches, components

Is there a switch which a user pushes/actuates to close, and which can be reopened with an electrical signal, and which does not consume power to stay closed or open? E.g. the user pushes the "Start" button, which closes the circuit and powers the device, then at the end of the device's cycle, it sends a signal to the switch to reset (open), cutting off its own power supply in the process. Is there a switch or component which does this, and if so, what is it called?

Optional bonus features:

- User can manually re-open the switch (e.g. by pressing it again)
- An electrical signal can also close the switch (e.g. a low-power microcontroller periodically turns on a higher-power device for, say, 30 seconds, then turns it back off)

Comment: Bistable relay.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does it exist: Latching Relay with Manual Switch](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/62472/does-it-exist-latching-relay-with-manual-switch)

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are called "Shunt trip release" modules.

Typically you buy a switch and buy the release module - which attaches to the switch. The release module is a way to electrically flick the switch.

It is extremely common in the electrical industry, as they are used to electrically activate circuit breakers etc.

Google "shunt trip release" and you will easily find tonnes of products that do what you want.

They only draw power to switch the switch, and you can get them to open or close or both, while the manual switch still works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [latching relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay#Latching_relay). The relay would be set when a user presses a momentary switch which provides current to the coil which moves the contact closed. The relay would be reset when the electronics use transistors to provide current to the coil which opens the contact.